# How to make C# WCF work in LAN?

Tags: c#, wpf, lan

I have created a WCF/WPF application. WCF is using Entity Framework to get data from database.
And on my local computer everything is working just fine.

But, how can I make this work in LAN? I have couple of computers in my home, so I wanted to work in this application on all of them.

This is how app.config from service look like:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ISKUService.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/ISKUService/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ISKUService.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Thanx!

What I have tried:

I have tried to change

```
<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/ISKUService/Service1/" />
```

into

```
<add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.13:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/ISKUService/Service1/" />
```

but no luck...

This is the error that I get on the other computer:

https://s4.postimg.io/otyu519xp/error.jpg

Comment: Did you just ask the same question a while ago? Post the error *in the question itself*, don't post an image. Just hit `Ctrl+C` to copy the text. Anyway, the message has nothing to do with a LAN. It's rather clear - you are missing the WCF configuration section from your app.config

Comment: BTW if you add a Service reference to a project, it will generate the proper configuration automatically. Have you copied the configuration from the *server* or some other project?

Comment: Your client configuration should point to the correct service endpoint.